# NSArray filtered using NSPredicate causes SIGABRT

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use the first block of code [here](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/), but it's written for an earlier version of swift.  So I updated it for Swift 4.  Here it is as in my Playground:

```
import UIKit

class Person: NSObject {
   let firstName: String
   let lastName: String
   let age: Int

   init(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int) {
      self.firstName = firstName
      self.lastName = lastName
      self.age = age
   }

   override var description: String {
     return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
   }
}

let alice = Person(firstName: "Alice", lastName: "Smith", age: 24)
let bob = Person(firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Jones", age: 27)
let charlie = Person(firstName: "Charlie", lastName: "Smith", age: 33)
let quentin = Person(firstName: "Quentin", lastName: "Alberts", age: 31)
let people = [alice, bob, charlie, quentin]

let bobPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName = %@", "Bob")
let smithPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "lastName = %@", "Smith")
let thirtiesPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "age >= 30")

(people as NSArray).filtered(using: bobPredicate)
```

On the last line `(people as NSArray).filtered(using: bobPredicate)`

I'm getting the error: `error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.  The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.`

I'm not sure how to resolve this error.  Thanks,

Comment: Don't needlessly extend `NSObject`. Don't use `NSArray`. Don't use `NSPredicate`. Use Swift arrays. Use the standard `filter` method of Swift collections.

Comment: Why are you going through that tutorial? Unless using a specific Obj-C based framework that requires you to use `NSPredicate`s (such as Realm), I'd recommend you switch to native Swift types.

Comment: The linked-to duplicate should answer your immediate question (NSPredicate is based on Key-Value coding, and in Swift 4 that requires members to be exposed explicitly to the Objective-C runtime). – Of course, as said above, not relying on the Objective-C runtime is the better alternative.

Comment: Ultimately, I'm trying to built a NSPredicate for getting at my CoreData.  So, yes I don't need to do any of this to work with the array, there was a purpose to it.  To cycle through NSPredicate attempts faster than try something, start my app, watch it fail, repeat.  So, maybe that is my mistake.  I can't play with NSPredicate this way?

Comment: I don't really understand the linked-to-duplicate but adding `@objc` above the `class Person: NSObject {` line didn't change anything.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't use the filter method of swit's array by passing a closure where you can decide the filtering conditions?

Comment: Yes.  See my comment above (sorry, I don't know how to reference a previous comment).

Comment: @CorySteers: You have to mark the *property,* not the class. In your case `@objc let firstName: String`.

Comment: @MartinR  OK.  Now I understand

Both:
`    @objcMembers
class Person: NSObject {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let age: Int
   ...
`
and
`
class Person: NSObject {
    @objc let firstName: String
        @objc let lastName: String
        @objc let age: Int
   ...
`
worked.

Comment: Oops.  where did all my formatting go?  :)